# What (will you/are going to) do if you win the lottery?

Tags: grammar

1. What will you do if you win the lottery?
   Or
2. What are you going to do if you win the lottery?

I chose (going to). I thought that "going to" is better than "will", because in this case you're certain about how you're going to spend your lottery money. However, It is incorrect.

Comment: They essentially mean the same thing.

Comment: There is an idea that some ELL classes have that for every sentence, exactly one of *will* or *are going to* is correct. This is totally wrong. In this sentence you can use either.

Comment: You aren't certain (!) that you will win the lottery.

Comment: *What **will** you do if X* sounds a bit over-optimistic to me. Given how unlikely it is that X (winning the lottery, here) will ever turn out to be true, I think it's better to ask *What **would** you do...?*

Answer (score 1):

Because winning the lottery cannot be predicted in advance, I would recommend using the subjunctive mood here:

"What would you do if you won the lottery?"

(Note that despite the form "won" being the same as the past tense, it refers in this case to an uncertain event in the future.)